# How to get index of object in handlebars each block

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm trying to implement simple quiz. I have first version when I created my html in javascript. Generating answers looked like this:

```
    for(var i in answers) {
        outAnswers += '<li data-answer="' + i + '">' + answers[i] + "</li>"; 
    }
```

Now I trying to use handlebars.js for this:

```
   <ul id="answers">
       {{#each choices}}
           <li>{{this}}</li>
       {/each}}
   </ul>
```

I don't know how I can check for correct answers in Handlebars version. Earlier I just added html data attribute and check
    if($(this).data('answer') === correctIndex)

My sample qestion looks like this:

```
{
 question: "This is example question", 
 choices: ["Answer1", "Answer2", "Answer3", "Answer4"], 
 correctAnswer: 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://handlebarsjs.com: "When looping through items in each, you can optionally reference the current loop index via {{@index}}". So to achieve with your template what you were achieving without it, your template would become:

```
<ul id="answers">
    {{#each choices}}
        <li data-answer="{{@index}}">{{this}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: +1 for @index approach. Just in case OP agrees to this solution and accepts it, please don't mind in updating the question title to "How to get index of object in handlebars each block" That will be good for future readers. Right ?